# Slickgrid css class to mark row dirty

Tags: slickgrid

When an item in a row has been edited, I want to mark the row as dirty using a CSS class.

What's the best way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**
I'm trying this, doesn't seem to work:

```
data.getItemMetadata = function (row) {
   if (data[row].isDirty == true) {
      return { "cssClasses": "dirty" };
   }
};
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function (e, args) {
   data[args.row].isDirty = true;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement `getItemMetadata()` and specify `cssClasses` for the dirty row.
(https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid)

Comment: The more you use SlickGrid, the more you like it!